# Moving text from a button to another using python tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-text, tkinter-button

```
def move(sp, t):
    if sp == "eightA":
        sps = eightA
    if t == "sixA":
        st = sixA
    if st == " ":
        # target is empty
        sps["text"] = " "
        st["text"] = str(sps["text"])
```

Hello Everyone, Im trying to make this function to "move" text from a tkinter button to another, lets say sp is what i want to move, and t is the target so i want to move text
from the button eightA to sixA, also note that i want to be able to use this function on any 2 buttons, Its hard to explain, but please help if you can, the code above is one i tried out of **alot** other which didnt work,
Thanks

Comment: you can use `st.config(text="text here")` to change text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Procedure

- Store the text on first button in a variable
- Configure first button to have no text
- Configure second button to have text stored in variable

### Example

```py
btn1 = tk.Button(text="Hello")
btn2 = tk.Button(text="Not Hello")

# store text on btn1 in a variable
txt = btn1['text']
# configure btn1 to have no text
btn1.config(text="")
# configure btn2 to have text stored in variable
btn2.config(text=txt)
```

So your function would look like

```py
def move(btn1, btn2):
    txt = btn1['text']
    btn1.config(text=" ")
    btn2.config(text=txt)
```

Comment: I have another error tho, for another function I need the entered parameter to be a string version of the button's name,  can i somehow convert the string to the button's name? thanks again!